# Do I need my own lawyer for lot line adjustment?

Tags: real-estate, property, ontario

I have a cottage, and behind the cottage is a single parcel of ~80 acres that the neighbour owns.

I made him an offer and he agreed to sell me 1.5 acres which would be added onto my existing lot due to local planning not allowing new lots within 300m of the lake.

I had my lawyer put together a purchase agreement, which after being signed the survey was completed, the lot adjustment was approved by municipality and everything is done.

Do I now need my lawyer involved again to complete the process, or because this is just a lot line adjustment will the sellers lawyer handle everything? This is in Ontario, Canada.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it done right, the best approach is to have your own lawyer do it so that the details will be handled by someone with your interests at heart.